# I can't insert new records from textarea in database - PHP and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

hi everyone :) i have problem with my php project. i can't insert records from textarea to database.this is my code:

vnesiMagacin.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_mmm");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$ID_Magacin     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ID_Magacin']);
$Ime            = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Ime']); 
$Adresa         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Adresa']); 
$Grad           = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Grad']); 
$KompZiroSmetka = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['KompZiroSmetka']); 
$Telefon        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Telefon']); 
$Email          = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Email']);

$sql="INSERT INTO magacin (ID_Magacin, Ime, Adresa, Grad, KompZiroSmetka, Telefon, Email) VALUES ('$ID_Magacin', '$Ime', '$Adresa','$Grad', '$KompZiroSmetka', '$Telefon','$Email')";

if ($ID_Magacin != '' && $Ime != '' && $Adresa  != '' && $Grad  != '' &&
              $KompZiroSmetka != '' && $Telefon != '' && $Email != '') {
    header('location:magacini.php');
} else {
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
         "window.alert('Moras da gi ispolnis site polinja.');".
         "history.back();".
         "</script>";
    exit;
}
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="vnesiMagacin.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="SSN">ID broj</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name" name="ID_Magacin" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="name">Ime na magacin</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name" name="Ime"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="address">Adresa</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name" name="Adresa"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="city">Grad</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="Grad" name="Grad"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="smetka">Zirosmetka</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="phone" name="KompZiroSmetka"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="pnohe">Telefon</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="phone" name="Telefon"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">E-mail</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="email" name="Email"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large" value="Zacuvaj">
            <a class="btn" href="klienti.php">Otkazi</a>
        </div>                  
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I use same code for another form and works well, but in this form i can't see my mistake.

Please for help!!!

Comment: please post some more information about the error you have got.

Comment: this works without error, but records from textarea not insert in database

Comment: What textarea? you do not have a <textarea> in your code

Comment: Your question does not contain a `<textarea>`, please include this part.

Comment: sorry, i mean on input type="text" :)

Answer (score 0):

try to replace (need to add proper quoting to echo statment)

```
"<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
  "window.alert('Moras da gi ispolnis site polinja.');"."history.back();".</script>";
```

with

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.alert('Moras da gi ispolnis site polinja.');history.back();</script>";
```

Also you need change your if() cause it's breaking your code and not goes to your query run so change your query run to above if() or proper place as you need

Comment: still can't insert records :(

Answer (score 0):

Please, correct your `echo()` statement as follows:

```
     echo 
      "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
      "window.alert('Moras da gi ispolnis site polinja.');"."history.back();".</script>;
```

Also, you are not doing anything with your query, you close it without dealing with your data when you typed this:

```
  if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); }
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Save your data some where:

```
$data=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
// Do something with your data
```

Comment: Your last comment makes little sense to me. `mysqli_query()` returns true or false for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` and such, it's fine to just check on that in an `if ()` and then discard the value.

Comment: As well your corrected `echo` statement is still faulty because it essentially says `echo "something" . </script>;` without putting `</script>` in `""`

Answer (score 0):

I'm noticing this part:

```
if ($ID_Magacin != '' && $Ime != '' && $Adresa  != '' && $Grad  != '' &&
              $KompZiroSmetka != '' && $Telefon != '' && $Email != '') {
    header('location:magacini.php');
} else { [...]
```

This part is saying that if every `$variable` is filled, the page should be redirected to magacini.php. Are you sure that's what you want? It is causing that if the `mysqli_query()` returns `FALSE`, you won't see the error because this part is after the `header('location:magacini.php');` is already set:

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

So even if the page prints `Error: somethingsomething` you will still be redirected to magacini.php and you will not see the error.

Comment: yes, when all records is insert in database, i want to exit from this page and go in magacini.php.
btw problem is same, i go in magacini.php without inserting records

Comment: Simply putting the `INSERT` part into `$sql` doesn't insert the records into the database, that only happens when you do `mysqli_query($con, $sql)` which I see happens much later (and after the `"`-mistake). But you only clarified about the `<input type="text">` after I posted this answer.

Comment: @user2440666 Updated my answer, could you remove the `header()` part and see if you get an error because you are now dealing with a different table (warehouse)?

Comment: thanks funkwurm, when i delete header(), screen showed me where is my mistake (foreign key in my database). now it works :) Thank you to everyone :)

Comment: You're welcome, could you click to accept my answer? That would be very helpful :)